# Makefile PHONY target execution order

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile:

```
.PHONY: all edit rtl

all: edit rtl csr

edit:
    p4 edit file1.v
    p4 edit file2.v

rtl: file1.v file2.v

csr: file3.h

file1.v:
    <generate file1.v>

file2.v:
    <generate file2.v>

file3.h:
    <generate file3.h>
```

If I run `make -j2 all` I have a race condition between `p4 edit` and `file1.v`. The only good solution I have come up with is:

```
.PHONY: all edit rtl _all

all:
    $(MAKE) edit
    $(MAKE) _all

_all: rtl csr

edit:
    p4 edit file1.v
    p4 edit file2.v
    p4 edit file3.h

rtl: file1.v file2.v

file1.v:
    <generate file1.v>

file2.v:
    <generate file2.v>

file3.h:
    <generate file3.h>
```

I want to avoid:

```
file1.v: edit
    <generate file1.v>

file2.v: edit
    <generate file2.v>
```

because if I run `make file1.v file2.v` edit will run multiple times. I also want to keep my edit target separate from file generation like:

```
file1.v:
    p4 edit file1.v
    <generate file1.v>
```

for performance reasons.

Is my solution the only good solution? Or does someone have a cleaner solution so I don't have to call make again?

Comment: Your comments about `edit` running multiple times are incorrect, in that `make` will not build any target more than once on any given run (even with `-j`).  However, you do appear to be converting one run into multiple runs by running sub-`make`s in the same directory.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want `edit: file1.v file2.v`? Surely you've thought of that. (And you do want to generate `file1.v` before you edit it, don't you?)

Comment: I'm anyway confused about the order you want.  You seem in a couple of places to be indicating that you want the `edit` target to be built *before* `file1.v` and `file2.v`, but the target names and recipes sure make it seem like `edit` depends on the files generated by the other two, such that it would need to run *after*.

Comment: Whatever the order you want, specifying a correct and complete prerequisite list for every target is the main solution.  Avoiding sub-`make`s in the same directory is also wise, unless you have good reason to trust that none of the `make` runs will build any of the same targets as any of the others.

Comment: csr appears to be .PHONY too.